# How do Transforms in WPF work?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I recently used a `TranslateTransform` in my WPF application to implement dragging a `UserControl` across the screen.  There is a new bug in that after the first time you drag it somewhere else on the screen, when you click on the "Title bar" on the control, it jumps back to where it was originally displayed.  It will still follow the mouse, but that initial jump is disconcerting.

I don't know what's going on, but this got me to wondering.  Since WPF controls don't have a left or top property of their own, unless you put them into a `Canvas`, and those are attached properties anyway, just what properties are being modified by the `TranslateTransform`?

Comment: Please add some code where you apply transformations

Comment: I'm not interested in what a particular transform does.  I'm interested in how they work in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF's layout and render passes have intrinsic knowledge of transforms. By modifying the `X` and `Y` properties of the `TranslateTransform`, you're causing the layout/render pass to take those new values into consideration when positioning the associated `FrameworkElement`.

To put it another way: the `TranslateTransform` is not modifying other properties, but by modifying *its* properties you are triggering another layout/render pass and thus affecting the on-screen positioning of the associated `FrameworkElement`.

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx) for more information.

Comment: So it seems that there must be some kind of coordinates kept internally somewhere that are affected by the transform, but they're not visible to the programmer.  Thanks.

Comment: WPF's layout system effectively calculates coordinates for each `FrameworkElement`. You might want to have a read of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) too.